# Haskell Concurrent.Channel: What is difference between this two codes?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, channel

Why this code

```hs
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TChan

main = do
  ch <- newTChanIO
  forkIO $ consumer ch 0
  forkIO $ consumer ch 1
  ----------------------
  forkIO $ producer ch
  ----------------------
  return ()


producer ch = loop 0
  where
    loop n = do
      atomically $ writeTChan ch n
      threadDelay (10^5 :: Int)
      loop (n+1)


consumer ch n = forever $ do
  v <- atomically $ readTChan ch
  print (n, v)
```

doesn't behave the same way as

```hs
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TChan

main = do
  ch <- newTChanIO
  forkIO $ consumer ch 0
  forkIO $ consumer ch 1
  ----------------------
  producer ch
  ----------------------
  return ()


producer ch = loop 0
  where
    loop n = do
      atomically $ writeTChan ch n
      threadDelay (10^5 :: Int)
      loop (n+1)


consumer ch n = forever $ do
  v <- atomically $ readTChan ch
  print (n, v)
```

The latter code's output is

```
(0,0)
(1,1)
(1,2)
(1,3)
(1,4)
(0,5)
(0,6)
(1,7)
...
```

But, the former one's output is only

```
(0,0)
```

I intended that `producer` indefinitely add a value to the channel queue `ch`, and `consumer` indefinitely take a value from `ch`.

The latter code acts as well as my intension, but the former one doesn't.

In the eventlog (ghc-events), block happens on an MVar in `producer` thread

```
4775372: cap 0: stopping thread 8 (blocked on an MVar)
```

Why the former code (forkIO $ producer ch) doesn't indefinitely run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#g:12:

> In a standalone GHC program, only the main thread is required to terminate in order for the process to terminate. Thus all other forked threads will simply terminate at the same time as the main thread (the terminology for this kind of behaviour is "daemonic threads").
>
> If you want the program to wait for child threads to finish before exiting, you need to program this yourself.

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch07.html#sec_reminders:

> [...] This tells us something important about how threads work in Haskell: *the program terminates when `main` returns, even if there are other threads still running*. The other threads simply stop running and cease to exist after `main` returns.